# Python SQL, how to keep program going after entering an invalid input

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Ok, so I have some code when creating a database.

Here's the code:

[image: The code]

So basically, the PhoneNumber is set to unique. If I enter a phone number that has already been entered the program stops and gives an error message (Because it is unique).

How do I get it to keep running or display a message saying "Phone number already taken please input another on" instead of ending

Thanks

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. [Edit] your question, and post your code as text. Indent your code by 4 spaces, and the site will automatically syntax highlight it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try catch` statement to do exception handle.

Comment: example please? I don't understand what a catch statement it

Comment: @James If you're going to take the lazy attitude of "didn't work sorry" - you don't deserve any help!